# Yet another Mysql database encoding chars on windows versus linux

Tags: java, mysql

The general problem is I have two mysql5 db's. One is on windows machine, where I'm developing, the other is on remote linux (ubuntu) server.

I'm building a fat jar with spring/hibernate.

On local machine and local mysql db everything is fine. I parse some web page using jsoup and store my results in database, and data is stored with polish encoding for example:
"sprzedaż Warszawa, Żoliborz, Potocka"

The same on linux server is:
"sprzeda? Warszawa, ?oliborz, Potocka"

Both databases have the same collation : utf8_unicode_ci

Columns are varchar.

When I run below sql on both databases:

SELECT DISTINCT C.collation_name, T.table_name 
FROM   information_schema.tables AS T, 
       information_schema.`collation_character_set_applicability` AS C 
WHERE  C.collation_name = T.table_collation 
       AND T.table_schema = DATABASE();

I get the same result : that collation is utf8_unicode_ci.

The db string is as follows:
jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbname?autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=true&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&characterEncoding=utf-8

Hibernate configuration as below:

```
@Bean
public SessionFactory sessionFactory() throws Exception {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "x.domain" });
    Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", false);
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer", false);
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.check_nullability", false);
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect");
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners", false);        
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.connection.CharSet", "utf8");
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.connection.characterEncoding", "utf8");
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.connection.useUnicode", true);
    sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties);
    sessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();

    return sessionFactoryBean.getObject();
}
```

I've spent hours trying to find a solution for this, unfortunately with no luck. I've changed collation to utf8_bin, changed column collation, db strings, hibernate config and nothing. Still the result is getting "?" instead of polish char on linux server. I would appreciate some advice. Thanks for reading.

Comment: the "yet another" part of your own title doesn't ring a bell? This problem was raised so many times, here and on other sites. just use google, would you?

Comment: You must also check that the right data go into the database, and are correctly presented to the user. So log byte arrays (Arrays.toString), and check that you are not somewhere using the default platform encoding. Or assume that the encoding is something. _It does not need to be the database, though MySQL makes life hard._

Comment: @JanOssowski as I've stated in my last sentence I've used google and stack overflow and didn't found a solution for this, though I tried many things regarding the collation and encoding settings. If you have something specific in mind please share. Anyway thanks for reading.

Comment: @JoopEggen I've added logging just before the hibernate generic DAO add method and in logs everything is fine. The chars are fine. So just before adding the to DB everything seems to be OK.

Comment: And getting them back? In java or DB tool? Unfortunately the entire flow has to be checked step wise.

Comment: Not truly know what you mean by get them back? The next thing is session.save which returns the id and after that I can use the remote DB client or check with mysql on a serwer. 

Other than that I can debug that in hibernate classes, but the object seems fine.